# Como fazer um select para carregar em outra página com dados xml

Tags: php, html, xml

Tenho xml com essa estrutura:

```
<produto>
    <id>1</id>  
    <descricao>Hamburguer 1</descricao>
    <observacao>Hambúrguer bovino (180g), recheado com queijo Emmental e envolto em anel de       bacon, cebola crispy e barbecue no pão de brioche.</observacao>
    <valor>41,00</valor>
    <img>imagem.png</img>
    <adicionais>
        <opcionais>
            <opcional1>Queijo</opcional1>
            <opcional2>Cebola</opcional2>
            <opcional3>Bacon</opcional3>
            <opcional4>Tomate</opcional4>
        </opcionais>
        <obrigatorios>
            <obrigatorio1>Mal passado</obrigatorio1>
            <obrigatorio2>Ao ponto</obrigatorio2>
            <obrigatorio3>Bem passado</obrigatorio3>
        </obrigatorios>
    </adicionais>
</produto>
```

E esse php com foreach:

```
        <?php 
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('dados.xml');
    ?>

<div class="title">
    <?php echo $xml->fantasia; ?>
</div>

    <?php foreach ($xml->produto as $registro): ?>

<div class="quadros">
    <span class="linha">
        <img src="<?php echo "img/" . $registro->img; ?>"  width=200>
    </span>
    <span class="linha">
        <p>Código: <?php echo $registro->id;  ?></p>
        <p>Descrição: <?php echo $registro->descricao;  ?></p>
        <p>Observação: <?php echo $registro->observacao;  ?></p>
        <p>Preço: <?php echo $registro->valor;  ?></p>

        <a style="text-align: center;" href="detalhes.php?id=<?php echo $registro->id;  ?>">
                <span class="">Alterar</span><br>
        </a>
    </span>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Preciso que saia em outra página php os adicionais do produto que selecionei (clicando no link "alterar"), mas não sei como faço esse filtro, alguém pode me ajudar? Sei que tenho que passar o filtro, mas não sei como.

```
<?php foreach ($registro->adicionais->opcionais as $opcionais): ?>
    <div class="linha">
    <p style="font-weight: bold;">Opcionais</p>
        <p><?php echo $opcionais->opcional1;  ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $opcionais->opcional2;  ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $opcionais->opcional3;  ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $opcionais->opcional4;  ?></p>
    </div>

    <?php foreach ($registro->adicionais->obrigatorios as $obrigatorios): ?>

    <div class="linha">
        <p style="font-weight: bold;">Obrigatorios</p>
        <p><?php echo $obrigatorios->obrigatorio1;  ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $obrigatorios->obrigatorio2;  ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $obrigatorios->obrigatorio3;  ?></p>
</div>
    
</div>
<br>
<br>    
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<a style="text-align: center;" href="detalhes.php?id=<?php echo $registro->id;  ?>">
   <span class="">Alterar</span><br>
</a>
```

Você está passando apenas o id do produto com GET.
Para continuar dessa forma poderia passar os adicionais como demais parâmetros GET.
Usando seu foreach dos adicionais vá concatenando em uma string no formato da requisição GET

```
?id=$id&opcional1=$opcional1&obrigatorio1=$obrigatorio1&...
```

Ou então utilize outro método, como POST, para isso eu trocaria seu link `<a>` por um `<form>` com todos os campos hidden deixando apenas o botão visível.